# Pandas count monthly occurrences with across-rows condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime, data-analysis

I have a Dataframe like this

```
                              oper_status
2012-01-01 00:26:54.250            0
2012-01-01 12:11:54.250            1
2012-01-01 13:57:54.250            2
2012-01-02 00:16:54.250            0
2012-01-02 14:26:54.250            1
2012-01-02 17:20:54.250            0
2012-01-04 08:21:54.250            0
2012-01-04 15:34:54.250            1
2012-01-04 19:45:54.250            0
2012-01-05 01:00:54.250            0
2012-01-05 12:46:54.250            1
2012-01-05 20:27:54.250            2
        (...)                    (...)
```

and I want to count how many times every month I have consecutive values with this pattern: 0,1,2.
I tried looping on the rows with iterrows() but it's very slow since I have a big dataset.
I also thought about using "diff" but I can't figure out a simple way to do it. Thanks

EDIT:
The expected output is like this

```
              count
time                      
2012-03-31     244
2012-04-30     65
2012-05-31     167
2012-06-30     33
2012-07-31     187
            ...     ...
2013-05-31     113
2013-06-30     168
2013-07-31     294
2013-08-31     178
2013-09-30     65
```

Comment: something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38792122/10197418)? also, are you using Python 3 or Python 2? the tags of your question are ambiguous in that respect...

Comment: please show an expected output

Comment: Thanks but that it's not what I mean. I need something that counts how many time I have 0,1,2 (in three consecutive row). I removed python 2, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counting sequential patterns is a two step process. First, build a sequence for each row, representing the pattern ending at that row:

```
df['seq'] = df.order_status.astype(str).shift(periods=0) + '-' + 
            df.order_status.astype(str).shift(periods=1) + '-' + 
            df.order_status.astype(str).shift(periods=2)

                      date  order_status    seq
0  2012-01-01 00:26:54.250             0    NaN
1  2012-01-01 12:11:54.250             1    NaN
2  2012-01-01 13:57:54.250             2  2-1-0
3  2012-01-02 00:16:54.250             0  0-2-1
4  2012-01-02 14:26:54.250             1  1-0-2
5  2012-01-02 17:20:54.250             0  0-1-0
6  2012-01-04 08:21:54.250             0  0-0-1
7  2012-01-04 15:34:54.250             1  1-0-0
8  2012-01-04 19:45:54.250             0  0-1-0
9  2012-01-05 01:00:54.250             0  0-0-1
10 2012-01-05 12:46:54.250             1  1-0-0
11 2012-01-05 20:27:54.250             2  2-1-0
```

Then, filter down to only the correct sequences and aggregate up to your desired level:

```
df['month'] = df.date.dt.month    
df[df.seq == '2-1-0'].groupby("month").month.count()

month
1    2
```

Alter as necessary to handle cases where you want patterns starting in a certain period, stopping there, entirely within, etc...