# counting birthdays per month per client in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-science

I have a dataframe with the birthdays of the users of specific clients in a dataframe, and i want to
count occurences per month, but also per client, so in the end id have all the occurences of birthdates per month for client #1, all the occurences of birthdates per month for client #2 etc..., similarly to what is described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38792122/how-to-group-and-count-rows-by-month-and-year-using-pandas) question in which they suggest using this:

```
df.groupby([df['birthdate'].dt.year.rename('year'), df['birthdate'].dt.month.rename('month')]).agg({'count'})
```

for a scenario where one wants to count the birthdays per month (not also per client).

How could i go about doing this?

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. It will be great if you can have a look at [ask] and then try to produce a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

If you want to group by month, year and client, you'll need to include the client column within the groupby() and [reset_index()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html?highlight=reset_index):

```
groupby([df['birthdate'].dt.year.rename('year'), df['birthdate'].dt.month.rename('month'), df['client']]).agg({'count'}).reset_index()
```

From there you can use [sort_values()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) to sort your dataframe as you wish.

Comment: this gives me the error "AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values" even though birthday is a daytime value

Comment: If you get that error your birthdate column is most likely not in datetime format. Try to assign that column that format for to_datetime(). df['birthdate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['birthdate'])